# downgrade angular 5 to 4.3.3 in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 but I need to know how to downgrade the angular dependencies from 5.0.0 to 4.3.3

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.12",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
```

Comment: change the versions that you just listed and then run npm install

Comment: you mean i will manually edit the version of dependencies and then run npm install ?

Comment: @vince yes.. edit package.json. set all angular packages to 4.3.3.. delete node_modules and run npm install

Comment: @SurajRao thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the `package.json` according to the following

```
 "dependencies": {
            "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
            "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
            "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
            "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
            "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",                
            "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
            "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",                
            "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
            "ionic-angular": "3.7.0",
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
            "ionicons": "3.0.0",
            "rxjs": "5.4.3",
            "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",                
            "zone.js": "0.8.17",
            // ...
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.0",
            "typescript": "2.3.4"
        },
```

And then just (Don't forget to delete the `node_module` folder from your project directory)

`npm install`

Done :)

Comment: Yes your answer is helpful. thank you.

Comment: Accept tha answer with the `right tick` on your question :) @vince

Comment: @KishanOza I've removed from your answer some dependencies that have nothing to do with Angular

Comment: Ok i didn't notice bro @sebaferreras